# How to stack multiple do loops in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, copy, range

The aim is to match two tables accroding to some specific words.

There are two tables each with 3 colums and rows(see pic). 
The value A2 (table 1) are being searched range A(table 2 ). That search of this value in table 2 range A shall continue until either the value is found in table 2 range A or the loop stops when a certain Cell (e.g. A30) is reached.For case 1, if the value in table 1 A2 is found in range A in table 2, the second value (e.g.in A3 table 1) shall be taken to search for that value in table 2 range A and so on until a sertain cell is reached again.For case 2, if the value A2 (table1) cannot be found in the given range A (table2), the value in the next colum B2 shall be search for in range B(table 2) until a certain cell is reached. If this isnt successfull as well the next step is to look for the value of C2(table1) in range C(table2).

The issue is to get the do loops in the right positions so as to the search of the values (table 1) in table 2 starts always with the values in Range A (table 1) when that value ( table 1) is found.

Update: Where I am stuck is to get the multiple Do-loops right. I guess I need 3 do-loops and my problem is to get the 3rd. do-loop (the very inner one) which does the checking of the values between the tables to jump to the very first do-loop after the value in question (table1) has been found in table 1. In other word, when the value A1 in table 1 is found the do-loop goes one row further to A2 and starts again. If nothing is found in table 2, pick up the value in B2(table1) and search again but in range "B" table 2.

I have also tried to include the command "loop until" when a certain cell number e.g cells(10,1) is reached. I guess here is also a buck init.

[image]

[image]

```
 Sub Import_Klicken()

 Dim wp As Workbook
 Dim ws As Workbook
 Dim c As Long, r As Long, rng As Range
 Dim w As Integer
 Dim t As Integer


 Set ws = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\a.xlsx")
 Set wp = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Yavuz\Desktop\t.xlsx")


  Do
    w = w + 1
    i = i + 1
    t = 0
      Do
         t = t + 1
         If ws.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(i, w).Value = wp.Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(t, w).Value Then
         wp.Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(t, w).Copy
        Exit Do

     End If
  Loop Until wp.Sheets("Tabelle2").Cells(t, w).Value = treu
     i = 0
Loop
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem you are facing is? Where do you think it is going wrong?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I have updated my comment.

Comment: Did you try to debug it? When you open your code, you can run it line by line by pressing F8.

Comment: I did. It jumps always from the third loop into the second but it is supposed to jump to the first loop when the searched value is found

Comment: you need to set a boolean variable to use as a flag that will transmit the information that you found the data from the inner loop into the second, and exit do that loop if flag is true. (don't forget to reset the flag to false on entering the second loop

Comment: I will try it out with the "for" command. Do-Loop seems to be more complicated and not suitable for my case.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with vlookup and hlookup commands... I can't quite tell what you are trying to do yet. Personally, I don't use VBA. I use excel functions, and if those are not enough, I move on to Python.

Comment: i have got the solution, shall i closed this question?